# Angular 9 lazy load each component of a module

Tags: angular, angular9

I have a module who has a big set of components that are accessed by different subroutes. I'm already lazy loading the module, but I'd like to know if it's possible to lazy load the subcomponents:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
      },
      {
        path: 'users',
        component: UsersComponent, // I want to lazy load that
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
      },
      {
        path: 'account',
        component: AccountComponent, // I want to lazy load that
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
      },
      {
        path: 'invoices',
        component: InvoicesComponent, // I want to lazy load that
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
      },
      {
        path: 'upgrade',
        component: StripeFormComponent, // I want to lazy load that
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Any idea if that's possible?

Comment: This is probably a bad idea. Better to just use seperate modules in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about component lazy-loading there: https://johnpapa.net/angular-9-lazy-loading-components/
But i think that separate each component to module is better idea